# Deleted complete OS from my Lenovo tablet

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, tablet, lenovo, operating-system

I was trying to root my Lenovo tablet x505x using Magisk patch image file method.And then I accidentally deleted my TWRP backup and now my Lenovo tab has no recovery or OS.

I downloaded the firmware file from the software (official Rescue and smart assistant) and extracted the boot,system,recovery image files and flashed them to my tablet using `adb`. When in `fastboot` mode .The image files are being sent to the tablet and are even getting flashed without any error but the thing is they are not getting correctly flashed into the tablet because the boot loop is just being repeated again and again.

```
Boot loader state --- Unlocked
```

Device: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/TABLETS/M-SERIES-TABLETS/TAB-M10-HD/ZA4K/ZA4K0017IN/

Comment: flash boot_a + recovery_a + system_a from fastboot, set slot a active

Comment: @alecxs
do you mean rename the file name and flash them?

Comment: When you boot into fastboot mode adb will not work. I assume from fastboot/bootloader you selected "boot into recovery" which ends fastboot mode. Which adb commands did you execute to install the images? As your tablet seem to be bootloader unlocked you should be able to directly flash the images files via `fastboot flash <destination_partition_name> <partition_image_file_name>`

Comment: @Robert I used the command  'fastboot flash recovery recovery.img'

Comment: And alecxs suggested to trybto flash IT to `recovery_a` instead of ` recovery`. It would be best of you would edit your question and include the commands you have expected and their output (as Text, Not as screenshot).